# how to add class to element from its id?

Tags: jquery, html

For some reason I can't set class of this element directly in class (a script somehow overrides it), so I want to do it on window load, by reading id and placing it as class. I want to get something like this:

```
<div id="mask" class="picture"></div>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
   $( "div.picture" ).addClass( $(this).attr('id'));
}
</script>
```

But this obviously does not work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `callBack` function of `addClass` at this context,

```
$( "div.picture" ).addClass(function(){ return this.id; });
```

Comment: @user2659948 Glad to help! :) And try to press tick mark present inside any one of the answers present here. That would help the future visitors to spot the correct one. And this is not a compulsion. :)

Answer (score 2):

try this in onload.in the question you are using `$(this).attr()` but actually you dont have that element reference in pageload.you have to loop over all the elements matched by `Jquery` selector and inside you can access each using `$(this)`

```
   $( "div.picture" ).each(function(){
     $(this).addClass( $(this).attr('id'));
   })
```